# Error in `transmute()`: Caused by error in `case_when()`:

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to run the code below (really long, sorry for that), but I get the error

Error in `transmute()`:
! Problem while computing `hændelsessted = ... %>% as.factor()`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Case 5 (`(`*Lokation (hændelsessted)`== "Aflastning- og midlertidige pladser" &`*Lokation (hændelsessted)`== "Øvrige tilbud til borgere med handicap" &`*Lokation (hændelsessted) `== "Rehabiliterin...`) must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector.

I can't seem to solve it. Can anyone help? Thank you!

```
UTH_data <- UTH %>% 
  transmute(
    rapportør = case_when(
      `*Faggruppe` == "Psykologisk personale" & `*Faggruppe` == "Psykologer og psykoterapeuter" & `*Faggruppe` == "Optikere, kontaktlinseoptikere og optometrister" &
      `*Faggruppe` == "Jordemødre" & `*Faggruppe` == "Andet personale" & `*Faggruppe` == "Kliniske diætister" & `*Faggruppe` == "Terapeuter og kiropraktorer" & `*Faggruppe` == "Trænende personale"
      & `*Faggruppe` == "Socialfagligt personale" & `*Faggruppe` == "Pædagogisk personale" & `*Faggruppe` == "Pædagoger og socialt fagligt personale" &
      `*Faggruppe` =="Andet klinisk personale" & `*Faggruppe` == "Teknisk disponent" & `*Faggruppe` == "Teknisk personale" ~ "Andet personale",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Ambulancepersonale" & `*Faggruppe` == "Ambulancbehandler" & `*Faggruppe` == "Ambulancebehandler" ~ "Ambulancepersonale",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Lægeligt personale" & `*Faggruppe` == "Læger" ~ "Lægeligt personale",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Tandlæger, tandplejere og tandteknikere" & `*Faggruppe` == "Tandplejefagligt personale" ~ "Tandlæger, tandplejere og tandteknikere",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Social- og sundhedsassistenter" & `*Faggruppe` == "Social- og sundhedshjælpere" ~ "Social- og sundhedsassistenter og -hjælpere",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Sundhedsfaglig visitator" ~ "Sundhedsfaglig visitator",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Radiografer" ~ "Radiografer",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Farmaceutisk personale" ~ "Farmaceutisk personale",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Bioanalytikere" ~ "Bioanalytikere",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Sygeplejersker" & `*Faggruppe` == "Sygeplejefagligt personale" ~ "Sygeplejefagligt personale",
      `*Sagstype` == "Patient UTH 2" & `*Sagstype` ==  "PatientPårørende UTH" & `*Sagstype` == "Pårørende UTH 2" ~ "Patienter og pårørende",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor(), # all others missing, then change to factor
    køn = case_when(
      Køn == "dame" & Køn ==  "Female" & Køn == "hun" & Køn ==  "hunkøn" & Køn == "kvinde" & Køn == "Kvinde" & Køn == "kvinder" & Køn == "Kvinder" & Køn == "kvindekvinde" & Køn == "pige"
      & Køn ==  "Pige" & Køn == "Dame" & Køn == "Hunkøn" ~ "Kvinde", 
      Køn == "dreng" & Køn == "Dreng" & Køn == "han" & Køn == "Han" & Køn == "hankøn" & Køn =="male" & Køn == "mad" & Køn =="Mand" & Køn == "mænd" & Køn == "MAnd" &
        Køn == "Ung mand" & Køn == "mand" & Køn =="M" & Køn =="m" ~ "Mand",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor(),
    hændelsessted = case_when(
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Aflastning- og midlertidige pladser" & `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Øvrige tilbud til borgere med handicap" &
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Rehabilitering" &  `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Misbrugsbehandling" & `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Sundhedsplejersker" &
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Akutfunktion" & `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Den kommunale tandpleje" & `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Forebyggelsescentre" &
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Kommunelæger" & `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Sundheds- og sygeplejecentre" & `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Sociale botilbud" &
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Andet" ~ "Andet kommunalt",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Regionale botilbud" & `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Terapeuter og kiropraktorer" & `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Tandlæger og tandplejere" ~ "Andet regionalt",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Apoteker" ~ "Apoteker",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Hjemmeplejen" ~ "Hjemmeplejen",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Hjemmesygeplejen", ~ "Hjemmesygeplejen",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Offentlige sygehuse", ~ "Offentlige sygehuse",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Plejebolig", ~ "Plejebolig",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Praktiserende læger (almen praksis)" ~ "Praktiserende læger (almen praksis)",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Privathospitaler og hospice" ~ "Privathospitaler og hospice",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Præhospital og ambulancer" ~ "Præhospital og ambulancer", 
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Speciallæger" ~ "Speciallæger",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Vagtlægeordningen" ~ "Vagtlægeordningen",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor(),
    alder = case_when(
      Alder == "0-9" & Alder < 10 ~ "0-9",
      Alder == "10-19" & Alder >= 10  & Alder <= 19 ~ "10-19 år",
      Alder == "20-29" & Alder >= 20  & Alder <= 29 ~ "20-29 år",
      Alder == "30-39" & Alder >= 30  & Alder <= 39 ~ "30-39 år",
      Alder == "40-49" & Alder >= 40  & Alder <= 49 ~ "40-49 år",
      Alder == "50-59" & Alder >= 50  & Alder <= 59 ~ "50-59 år",
      Alder == "60-69" & Alder >= 60  & Alder <= 69 ~ "60-69 år",
      Alder == "70-79" & Alder >= 70  & Alder <= 79 ~ "70-79 år",
      Alder == "80-89" & Alder >= 80  & Alder <= 89 ~ "80-89 år",
      Alder == "90-99" & Alder >= 90 ~ "90+ år",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor(),
    alvorlighed = case_when(
      alvorlighed == "Ingen skade" ~ "Ingen skade",
      alvorlighed == "Mild" ~ "Mild",
      alvorlighed == "Moderat" ~ "Moderat",
      alvorlighed == "Alvorlighed" ~ "Alvorlig",
      alvorlighed == "Dødelig" ~ "Dødelig",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor(),
    hændelsestype = case_when(
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Ambulancer, akutbiler, helikoptere mv." ~ "Ambulancer, akutbiler, helikoptere mv.",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Behandling og Pleje" ~ "Behandling og pleje",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Gasser og luft" ~ "Gasser og luft",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Infektioner" ~ "Infektioner",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Kirurgisk behandling herunder ECT, anæstesi mv." ~ "Kirurgisk behandling, herunder ECT, anæstesi mv.",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Medicinsk udstyr, hjælpemidler, Røntgen mv." ~ "Medicinsk udstyr, hjælpemidler, røntgen mv.",      
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Patientidentifikation" ~ "Patientidentifikation",      
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Præhospital behandling" ~ "Præhospital behandling",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Selvskade og selvmord" ~ "Selvskade og selvmord",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Teknisk disponering" ~ "Teknisk disponering",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Anden utilsigtet hændelse" ~ "Anden utilsigtet hændelse",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Blod og blodprodukter" ~ "Blod og blodprodukter",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Henvisninger, ind/udskrivelse og medicinlister" ~ "Henvisninger, ind/udskrivelse og medicinlister",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Overlevering af information, ansvar, dokumentation " ~ "Overlevering af information, ansvar, dokumentation",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Patientuheld herunder bl.a. fald og brandskader" ~ "Patientuheld, herunder bl.a. fald og brandskader",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Prøver, undersøgelser og prøvesvar" ~ "Prøver, undersøgelser og prøvesvar",
      "DPSD Hovedgruppe" == "Sundhedsfaglig visitation, telefonkonsultation" ~ "Sundhedsfaglig visitation, telefonkonsultation",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor(),
    problem = case_when(
      "DPSD Problem" == "Andet" ~ "Andet",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Clostridium" ~ "Clostridium",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Fejl eller mangler i medicinlisten" ~ "Fejl eller mangler i medicinlisten",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Fejl ved brugsanvisning /mærkning" ~ "Fejl ved brugsanvisning eller mærkning",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert / manglende antal/ mængde" ~ "Forkert/manglende antal/mængde",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert blanding" ~ "Forkert blanding",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert indgift/administrationsvej" ~ "Forkert indgift/administrationsvej",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert kropsdel/side/sted" ~ "Forkert kropsdel/side/sted",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert opbevaringsform (temperatur mv.)" ~ "Forkert opbevaringsform (temperatur mv.)",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert placering" ~ "Forkert placering",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert rate/flow/koncentration" ~ "Forkert rate/flow/koncentration",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert tidspunkt" ~ "Forkert tidspunkt",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert vurdring af behov og niveau" ~ "Forkert vurdring af behov og niveau",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkerte lægemiddeloplysninger" ~ "Forkerte lægemiddeloplysninger",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forsinket" ~ "Forsinket",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forsinket reaktion på prøvesvar" ~ "Forsinket reaktion på prøvesvar",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Hængning" ~ "Hængning",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ikke bestilt/rekvireret" ~ "Ikke bestilt/rekvireret",
      "DPSD Problem" == "ikke modtaget" ~ "Ikke modtaget",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ikke tilgængeligt" ~ "Ikke tilgængeligt",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Instrumenter, servietter mv. efterladt i pt." ~ "Instrumenter, servietter mv. efterladt i patient",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Lægemiddel ikke bestilt/rekvireret" ~ "Lægemiddel ikke bestilt/rekvireret",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Mangelfuld funktionalitet" ~ "Mangelfuld funktionalitet",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Mangelfuld/fejlagtig" ~ "Mangelfuld/fejlagtig",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Manglende (ikke  sendt, modtaget, set)" ~ "Manglende (ikke  sendt, modtaget, set)",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Medicin ikke givet" ~ "Medicin ikke givet",
      "DPSD Problem" == "MRSA / ESBL (Methicillin-resistente)" ~ "MRSA/ESBL (Methicillin-resistente)",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Personalets vurdering af pt.s fysiske formåen" ~ "Personalets vurdering af patientens fysiske formåen",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Påvirket af rusmidler/alkohol/medicin" ~ "Påvirket af rusmidler/alkohol/medicin",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Rusmidler" ~ "Rusmidler",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Sotwarefejl" ~ "Softwarefejl",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Træningsredskaber" ~ "Træningsredskaber",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Uhensigtsmæssig mærkning" ~ "Uhensigtsmæssig mærkning",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Urinvejskatetre" ~ "Urinvejskatetre",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ødelagt lægemiddel" ~ "Ødelagt lægemiddel",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Brugerfejl" ~ "Brugerfejl",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Clostridium, E.Coli" ~ "Clostridium, E.Coli",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Fejl i diagnostik" ~ "Fejl i diagnostik",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Fejl ved design" ~ "Fejl ved design",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert administration" ~ "Forkert administration",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert dosis" ~ "Forkert dosis",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert indikation" ~ "Forkert indikation",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert ordination" ~ "Forkert ordination",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert procedure" ~ "Forkert procedure",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert styrke/antal" ~ "Forkert styrke/antal",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert udført" ~ "Forkert udført",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert/mangelfuld formidling" ~ "Forkert/mangelfuld formidling",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkerte oplysninger i medicinliste" ~ "Forkerte oplysninger i medicinliste",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forsinket eller forlænget" ~ "Forsinket eller forlænget",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forsinket vurdering" ~ "Forsinket vurdering",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ikke anlagt" ~ "Ikke anlagt",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ikke fjernet" ~ "Ikke fjernet",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ikke sendt/modtaget" ~ "Ikke sendt/modtaget",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ikke udført" ~ "Ikke udført",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Kvælning" ~ "Kvælning",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Mangelfuld" ~ "Mangelfuld",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Mangelfuld indikation" ~ "Mangelfuld indikation",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Mangelfuldt angivelse af tidspunkt" ~ "Mangelfuld angivelse af tidspunkt",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Manglende dokumentation" ~ "Manglende dokumentation",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Manglende kapacitet" ~ "Manglende kapacitet",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Manglende medicinliste" ~ "Manglende medicinliste",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Manglende patientoplysninger" ~ "Manglende patientoplysninger",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Med kniv/våben" ~ "Med kniv/våben",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Medicin ikke indtaget, herunder fravalg" ~ "Medicin ikke indtaget, herunder fravalg",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Overskredet udløbsdato" ~ "Overskredet udløbsdato",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Problemer med sterilitet" ~ "Problemer med sterilitet",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Recept ikke håndteret/afsendt korrekt" ~ "Recept ikke håndteret/afsendt korrekt",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Rømning" ~ "Rømning",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Sårinfektion" ~ "Sårinfektion",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Udspring" ~ "Udspring",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Uhensigtsmæssighed" ~ "Uhensigtsmæssighed",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Vold fra medpatient" ~ "Vold fra medpatient",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Cave" ~ "Cave",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Drukning" ~ "Drukning",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Fejl i systemet" ~ "Fejl i systemet",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert" ~ "Forkert",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert bestilt/rekvireret" ~ "Forkert bestilt/rekvireret",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert gas/luftart" ~ "Forkert gas/luftart",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert indløbshastighed" ~ "Forkert indløbshastighed",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert mærkning af beholder eller udtag" ~ "Forkert mærkning af beholder eller udtag",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert patient" ~ "Forkert patient",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert produkt" ~ "Forkert produkt",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert tid/dag (dosispakke-/æske)" ~ "Forkert tid/dag (dosispakke-/æske)",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert udleveret" ~ "Forkert udleveret",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkert/manglende mærkning" ~ "Forkert/manglende mærkning",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forkerte patientoplysninger" ~ "Forkerte patientoplysninger",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Forsinket prøvesvar" ~ "Forsinket prøvesvar",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Fysiske forhold (bl.a. inventar, møbler, gulve)" ~ "Fysiske forhold (bl.a. inventar, møbler, gulve)",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ikke bestilt/forkert bestilte hjælpemidler" ~ "Ikke bestilt/forkert bestilte hjælpemidler",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ikke formidlet" ~ "Ikke formidlet",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ikke skrevet/sendt" ~ "Ikke skrevet/sendt",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Inficeret protese" ~ "Inficeret protese",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Lift/hjælpemiddel/arbejdsredskaber" ~ "Lift/hjælpemiddel/arbejdsredskaber",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Mangelfuld dosis" ~ "Mangelfuld dosis",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Mangelfuld vurdering" ~ "Mangelfuld vurdering",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Mangelfuldt effektueret" ~ "Mangelfuldt effektueret",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Manglende dosering/blanding" ~ "Manglende dosering/blanding",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Manglende kontrol/observation" ~ "Manglende kontrol/observation",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Med medicin" ~ "Med medicin",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Medicin ikke leveret/fejlleveret" ~ "Medicin ikke leveret/fejlleveret",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Patientens vurdering af egen fysiske formåen" ~ "Patientens vurdering af egen fysiske formåen",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Produktionsfejl" ~ "Produktionsfejl",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Recept ikke på server" ~ "Recept ikke på server",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Skade påført, herunder forbrænding" ~ "Skade påført, herunder forbrænding",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Transportfejl" ~ "Transportfejl",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Uhensigtsmæssig emballage" ~ "Uhensigtsmæssig emballage",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ukendt" ~ "Ukendt",
      "DPSD Problem" == "Ødelagt emballage" ~ "Ødelagt emballage",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor(),
    årstal = case_when(
      `*Opret dato [Year]-Trend` == "2018" ~ "2018",
      `*Opret dato [Year]-Trend` == "2019" ~ "2019",
      `*Opret dato [Year]-Trend` == "2020" ~ "2020",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor(),
    proces = case_when(
      "DPSD Proces" == "Absentering/ forladt institution" ~ "Absentering/forladt institution",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Aktivt implantabelt udstyr" ~ "Aktivt implantabelt udstyr",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Alarmkald, hjertestopkald, nødkald mv." ~ "Alarmkald, hjertestopkald, nødkald mv.",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Anden skade" ~ "Anden skade", 
      "DPSD Proces" == "Andet udstyr" ~ "Andet udstyr",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Andre gasarter" ~ "Andre gasarter",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Bestilling, rekvisition" ~ "Bestilling, rekvisition",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Brandskade" ~ "Brandskade",
      "DPSD Proces" == "CVK, venflon mm." ~ "CVK, venflon mm.",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Dispensering (Dosering, optælling, blanding)" ~ "Dispensering (dosering, optælling, blanding)",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Elektroniske Kommunikationssystemer" ~ "Elektroniske Kommunikationssystemer",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Engangsudstyr" ~ "Engangsudstyr",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Erkendelse af kritisk forværring" ~ "Erkendelse af kritisk forværring",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Fald" ~ "Fald",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Fysisk og medicinsk tvang" ~ "Fysisk og medicinsk tvang",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Fysiske rammer" ~ "Fysiske rammer",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Genoptræning" ~ "Genoptræning",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Henvisning/visitation" ~ "Henvisning/visitation",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Hjælpemidler" ~ "Hjælpemidler",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Hudinfektion (fx bylder og inficerede sår)" ~ "Hudinfektion (f.eks. bylder og inficerede sår)",
      "DPSD Proces" == "I patientjournal" ~ "I patientjournal",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ilt (oxygen)" ~ "Ilt (oxygen)",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Infektion efter operation" ~ "Infektion efter operation",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Instruktion og rådgivning" ~ "Instruktion og rådgivning",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Klinisk vurdering" ~ "Klinisk vurdering",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ledsaget patienttransport" ~ "Ledsaget patienttransport",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Mave-tarminfektion" ~ "Mave-tarminfektion",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Medicinmodul, FMK, Receptserver mv." ~ "Medicinmodul, FMK, receptserver mv.",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Multiresistente bakterier" ~ "Multiresistente bakterier",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Netværk, servere, internet mv" ~ "Netværk, servere, internet mv.",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Opbevaring" ~ "Opbevaring",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Opfølgning på undersøgelse/ prøver" ~ "Opfølgning på undersøgelse/prøver",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Opsporing (diagnostik) og forebyggelse" ~ "Opsporing (diagnostik) og forebyggelse",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ordination" ~ "Ordination",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Overdragelse af ansvar, vagtskit mv." ~ "Overdragelse af ansvar, vagtskit mv.",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Patientjournalsystemer, dagbog mv." ~ "Patientjournalsystemer, dagbog mv.",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Praksissystemer/lægesystemer" ~ "Praksissystemer/lægesystemer",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Rekvisition" ~ "Rekvisition",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Røntgensystemer" ~ "Røntgensystemer",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Sedation uden anæstesi" ~ "Sedation uden anæstesi",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Selvmordsforsøg" ~ "Selvmordsforsøg",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Skærmning" ~ "Skærmning",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Strømsvigt (forsyningssvigt)" ~ "Strømsvigt (forsyningssvigt)",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Teknologi" ~ "Teknologi",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Transport/ forsendelse" ~ "Transport/forsendelse",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Tryksår" ~ "Tryksår",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Undersøgelse/Prøvetagning" ~ "Undersøgelse/prøvetagning",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ved medicinering" ~ "Ved medicinering",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ved overlevering ekstern  (herunder transport)" ~ "Ved overlevering ekstern. herunder transport",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ved transfusion af blod og blodprodukter" ~ "Ved transfusion af blod og blodprodukter",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Vurdering" ~ "Vurdering",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Administration (fx udlev, indgift, identifikation)" ~ "Administration (f.eks. udlevering, indgift, identifikation)",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Alarmering" ~ "Alarmering",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ambulancer" ~ "Ambulancer",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Andet" ~ "Andet",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Andre forsyningssystemer, vand, trykluft" ~ "Andre forsyningssystemer, vand, trykluft",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Anæstesi" ~ "Anæstesi",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Behandlingsleje/stol" ~ "Behandlingsleje/stol",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Bookingsystemer" ~ "Bookingsystemer",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Brud på hygiejnen" ~ "Brud på hygiejnen",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Diagnostisk og terapeutisk stråleudstyr (Rgt. mv)" ~ "Diagnostisk og terapeutisk stråleudstyr (røntgen mv.)",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Elektromekanisk udstyr" ~ "Elektromekanisk udstyr",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Emballage mv" ~ "Emballage mv.",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Epikrise" ~ "Epikrise",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Erstatnings-cpr.-nummer" ~ "Erstatnings-cpr.-nummer",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Forberedelse til operation" ~ "Forberedelse til operation",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Fysisk visitation" ~ "Fysisk visitation",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Genbrugeligt udstyr" ~ "Genbrugeligt udstyr",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Helikopter" ~ "Helikopter",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Hjertestopbehandling" ~ "Hjertestopbehandling",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Hospitals hardware" ~ "Hospitalshardware",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Håndtering/behandling af prøvemateriale" ~ "Håndtering/behandling af prøvemateriale",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ikke aktivt implantabelt udstyr" ~ "Ikke aktivt implantabelt udstyr",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Indlæggelse, indflytning, overflytning" ~ "Indlæggelse, indflytning, overflytning",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Information/ Dokumentation" ~ "Information/dokumentation",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Interaktion" ~ "Interaktion",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Kommunikation" ~ "Kommunikation",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Luftvejsinefktion" ~ "Luftvejsinefktion",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Medicinafstemning" ~ "Medicinafstemning",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Modtagelse af svar" ~ "Modtagelse af svar",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Mærkning" ~ "Mærkning",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Observation" ~ "Observation",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Operationen/ECT" ~ "Operationen/ECT",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Oplysninger om ordinationer mv. ekskl. medicin" ~ "Oplysninger om ordinationer mv. ekskl. medicin",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Optisk udstyr" ~ "Optisk udstyr",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ordination, receptkontrol" ~ "Ordination, receptkontrol",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Patientens lejring" ~ "Patientens lejring",
      "DPSD Proces" == "PC'er og andet decentralt it-udstyr" ~ "PC'er og andet decentralt it-udstyr",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Reaktion på prøve-/undersøgelsessvar" ~ "Reaktion på prøve-/undersøgelsessvar",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Respirations udstyr" ~ "Respirationsudstyr",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Rådgivning" ~ "Rådgivning",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Selvmord" ~ "Selvmord",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Sepsis (blodforgiftning)" ~ "Sepsis (blodforgiftning)",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Sonder, katetre, dræn mv." ~ "Sonder, katetre, dræn mv.",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Støttesystemer, diktering mv." ~ "Støttesystemer, diktering mv.",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Telefoni, radiokommunikation generelt" ~ "Telefoni, radiokommunikation generelt",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Transportmidler, elevatorer, biler" ~ "Transportmidler, elevatorer, biler",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Udskrivning, udflytning" ~ "Udskrivning, udflytning",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Urinvejsinfektion" ~ "Urinvejsinfektion",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ved modtagelse" ~ "Ved modtagelse",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ved overlevering internt (herunder transport)" ~ "Ved overlevering internt, herunder transport",
      "DPSD Proces" == "Ved undersøgelser og prøvetagning/ svar" ~ "Ved undersøgelser og prøvetagning/-svar",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor(),
    rolle = case_when(
      `*Rolle i hændelsen` == "Andet" ~ "Andet",
      `*Rolle i hændelsen` == "Opdagelsessted" ~ "Opdagelsessted",
      `*Rolle i hændelsen` == "Patientovergang" ~ "Patientovergang",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor()
  )
```

Comment: Hi Mathilde. While `case_when` is in general fine for recoding in your case I would suggest to use a join or a lookup table and at least use `%in%`. Doing so will simplify your code considerably and is less error prone and easier to debug. Also, IMHO `&` is the wrong operator, i.e. it should be `|` (or). As is it's and without a snippet of your data to run the code it's hard to figure out where you misspecified your `case_when`.

Comment: Also, remember the M in MRE stands for *minimal*.  We need only to see the problematic `case_when` (and your test data), not all the others.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help!

My code now works for the variable "rapportør" but not for "hændelsessted". However, I believe I set up similar conditions for both variables and therefore cannot find out what the problem is.

```
UTH_data <- UTH %>% 
  transmute(
    rapportør = case_when(
      `*Faggruppe` %in% c("Psykologisk personale", "Psykologer og psykoterapeuter", "Optikere, kontaktlinseoptikere og optometrister", "Jordemødre",
                          "Andet personale", "Kliniske diætister", "Terapeuter og kiropraktorer", "Trænende personale", "Socialfagligt personale",
                          "Pædagogisk personale", "Pædagoger og socialt fagligt personale", "Andet klinisk personale", "Teknisk disponent","Teknisk personale")
      ~ "Andet personale",
      `*Faggruppe` %in% c("Ambulancepersonale", "Ambulancbehandler", "Ambulancebehandler") ~ "Ambulancepersonale",
      `*Faggruppe` %in% c("Lægeligt personale", "Læger") ~ "Lægeligt personale",
      `*Faggruppe` %in% c("Tandlæger, tandplejere og tandteknikere", "Tandplejefagligt personale") ~ "Tandlæger, tandplejere og tandteknikere",
      `*Faggruppe` %in% c("Social- og sundhedsassistenter", "Social- og sundhedshjælpere") ~ "Social- og sundhedsassistenter og -hjælpere",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Sundhedsfaglig visitator" ~ "Sundhedsfaglig visitator",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Radiografer" ~ "Radiografer",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Farmaceutisk personale" ~ "Farmaceutisk personale",
      `*Faggruppe` == "Bioanalytikere" ~ "Bioanalytikere",
      `*Faggruppe` %in% c("Sygeplejersker", "Sygeplejefagligt personale") ~ "Sygeplejefagligt personale",
      `*Sagstype` %in% c("Patient UTH 2", "PatientPårørende UTH", "Pårørende UTH 2") ~ "Patienter og pårørende",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor(),
hændelsessted = case_when(
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` %in% c("Aflastning- og midlertidige pladser", "Øvrige tilbud til borgere med handicap", "Rehabilitering",
                                         "Misbrugsbehandling", "Sundhedsplejersker", "Akutfunktion", "Den kommunale tandpleje", "Forebyggelsescentre",
                                         "Kommunelæger", "Sundheds- og sygeplejecentre", "Sociale botilbud", "Andet") ~ "Andet kommunalt",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` %in% c("Regionale botilbud", "Terapeuter og kiropraktorer", "Tandlæger og tandplejere") ~ "Andet regionalt",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Apoteker" ~ "Apoteker",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Hjemmeplejen" ~ "Hjemmeplejen",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Hjemmesygeplejen", ~ "Hjemmesygeplejen",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Offentlige sygehuse", ~ "Offentlige sygehuse",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Plejebolig", ~ "Plejebolig",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Praktiserende læger (almen praksis)" ~ "Praktiserende læger (almen praksis)",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Privathospitaler og hospice" ~ "Privathospitaler og hospice",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Præhospital og ambulancer" ~ "Præhospital og ambulancer", 
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Speciallæger" ~ "Speciallæger",
      `*Lokation (hændelsessted)` == "Vagtlægeordningen" ~ "Vagtlægeordningen",
      TRUE ~ as.character(NA)) %>% as.factor())
```

Can you see what the problem is? The error message is:
Error in `transmute()`:
! Problem while computing `hændelsessted = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Case 5 (``*Lokation (hændelsessted) `%in% c("Aflastning- og midlertidige pladser", "Øvrige tilbud til borgere med handicap", "Rehabilitering", "Misbrugsbehandling", "Sundhedsplejersker", "Akutfunktion...`) must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector.

Thank you in advance :)

Best, Mathilde